# Как удалить значение из словаря во время цикла for

Tags: python, циклы

Как-то неожиданно столкнулся с такой проблемой. Во время цикла `for` по словарю мне нужно удалять из него записи, но как не крути вылазит ошибка :

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Я даже пробовал делать снапшот словаря перед итерацией и итерировать двойника при этом удаляя из оригинала.

Пример:

```
>>> ot={12:'wqe',13:'wqe',14:'wqe',15:'wqe'}
>>> ot1=ot
>>> for i in ot1:
...  del ot[i]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Как удалять правильно?

upd:
разобрался,

снапшот был уместен, но сделан чуть чуть неправильно
вот так правильно:

```
>>> ot={12:'wqe',13:'wqe',14:'wqe',15:'wqe'}
>>> ot1=ot.copy()
>>> for i in ot1:
...  del ot[i]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете причину происходящего.
Вы задаете вопрос **Как удалять правильно**, но верный вопрос
**Как копировать правильно?**
Вы передаете ссылку на объект из ot в ot1, то есть при этом ot и ot1 дают указатель на один и тот же словарь.
**ПРИМЕР**

```
x=['wtf', 'justdoit']
x1=x
x1[0]='omg'
print x
>> ['omg', 'justdoit']
```

Comment: На самом деле копирование это один из вариантов, который я пробовал и похоже единственный верный. Меня просто удивило то что python не дал мне удалять значение из словаря во время цикла, хотя на самом деле он удаляет и сразу после первого удаления выдает ошибку.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, это сделано специально. Что-то вроде внутренней защиты от неправильного программирования.

Comment: Да, действительно. Если удалять пару ключ-значение из итерируемого объекта (словаря, например), то теряется значение длины, тем самым, **for** в недоумении

Answer (score 3):

Возможно правильнее было бы написать так:

```
>>> ot={12:'wqe',13:'wqe',14:'wqe',15:'wqe'}

>>> for i in ot**.keys()**:
...  del ot[i]
```

Comment: `dict.keys()` возвращает список на Python 2, поэтому это сработает. Но на Python 3, код снова сломается: [нужно явно копировать ключи](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454614/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы можно было удалять элементы из словаря во время итерации, необходимо скопировать ключи:

```
d = {12:'wqe',13:'wqe',14:'wqe',15:'wqe'}
# ...
for key in list(d):
    if condition(key):
        del d[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас код намекает на то, что элемент будет удаляться по ключу, а не его значению.

```
d = {12:'wqe',13:'wqe',14:'wqe',15:'wqe'}
for key in list(d):
    if key == max(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
        del d[key]
```

И не получается вашим методом почему-то.
output:
    {12: 'wqe', 13: 'wqe', 14: 'wqe', 15: 'wqe'}